# Android change actionbar menu when you change layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I am making a simple notepad app and I need help changing the ActionBar drop down menu. I want the main layout to have options for a new note and to reach settings but I need the menu to change when the user enter the note editor. I already have the menus made I just haven't found out how to switch to the different menu when I change to the different layout.

Comment: You need to inflate another menu in the onCreateOptionsMenu()

Comment: Could you provide me with a small example of what you mean? I'm fairly new to programming with android.

Comment: @joaquin Sorry I was on my phone at the time and didn't see it. That seems to fix it half way. The menu does change but I have to click on the ActionBar menu button for it to register the change.I have he code keeping track of the current layout through the R id of the layout everytime it changes and the conditional for the OnPrepareOptionMenu is   
    
    if(currentLay == R.id.mainLayout){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }

Comment: You should call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method to register the change instead of clicking the action bar.

Comment: @joaquin Would that go inside the 'onPrepareOptionMenu()' conditional before 'getMenuInflator()' or under 'menu.clear()'?

Comment: None of them. The main idea is that you create a menu when the app starts, OK. Then, for X reason you need to change the menu! So you call the method invalidateOptionsMenu(). This method will call onPrepareOptionsMenu() and voila, you'll have your new menu inflated

Comment: @joaquin Ok. I got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**main_menu.xml** (inside *res/menu folder*)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idOne" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Title 1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idTwo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Title 2"/>
</menu>
```

**In your Activity**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.idOne:
            doSomething();
            return true;

        case R.id.idTwo:
            doSomething2();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/* Above is presented the standard way of inflating a menu on Activity creation.
* When you need to change it later then you must override this method
* (also in your Activity)
*/
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    menu.clear(); //clears the current menu
    if (evaluateSomeCondition)
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.another_menu, menu);
    else if (evaluateSomeOtherCondition)
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.yet_another_menu, menu);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```